# Can I explicitly dump processor cache content to a file?

Tags: c, file, caching

For some reason, I'd like to know the content of processor caches at arbitrary point of my C program. Is there anyway I can write contents in the cache to a file?

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't know anything about your processor, its type, or its cache, or anything other related to that.

If you want to access this data, you would need OS-level functionality that supports it (which could potentially be callable from C). You need to look at your OS, and potential other choices, to find out if they support it.

Comment: The OS will only be able to support such a functionality if it is also supported by the CPU architecture. I am unaware of any CPU architecture which would support this. Such a feature is probably only supported by CPU emulators.